# How to avoid overfitting by entities in short text classifcation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation, text-classification

I am binary classifying headlines. This headlines are between 1 to 7 words, and sometimes include the name of the person who created them or locations.
I am able to classify with 81% precision but when I examine the features (words) that influence to each classification group I notice that many names classify best a specific group because they by random were presence only on 1 group.

I though about 2 solutions: 
1. Using NER to filter entities
2. Increasing regularization (still not succeeded with it)

What is the best way to handle this overfitting? 
And if increasing the lambda value is the answer, so how it is done with sklearn LogisticRegressionCV?

The relevant code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
X_train_stem_u = vectorizer_stem_u.fit_transform(X_train)

X_prepeared_data_train = X_train_stem_u 
selected_vectorizer = vectorizer_stem_u 

clf =  LogisticRegressionCV(cv=5,max_iter=800).fit(X_prepeared_data_train, y_train)#solver='liblinear',penalty='l1',

X_prepeared_data_test = selected_vectorizer.transform(X_test) 



predicted = clf.predict(X_prepeared_data_test)
print(np.mean(predicted == y_test))

import eli5

eli5.show_weights(clf, vec=selected_vectorizer, top=1500,
                  target_names=["group1","group2"])
```

And some na,es example features:

```
+7.323  peter
+6.143  ing
+6.033  enabl
+5.918  anand
+5.893  jose
```

Comment: Hi, any code to share ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Questions like that are better suited for [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BenjaminBreton I actually wrote it on cross-validaited and somehow it got here